# Django model works on local but not after deploy

Tags: python, django, forms

I am making a simple personal website. I make a box to input user data (name, email, and message). I want this data is sent to my django admin. I have test it and it works in local. But when i deploy it, i didn't get any data whenever i submit from the box. Note : i do not use django form for some reason. I want to use my own custom form.

this is my **views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import Feedback
from .forms import FeedbackForm

def index(request):
    if (request.method == "POST"):
        name = request.POST.get("Name")
        email = request.POST.get("Email")
        message = request.POST.get("Message")
        record = Feedback(name=name, email=email, message=message)
        record.save()          
    
    return render(request, 'main.html')
```

this is my **models.py**

```
from django.db import models

class Feedback(models.Model) :
        name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
        email = models.EmailField()
        message = models.CharField(max_length=200)

        def __str__(self):
            return self.name
```

this is my **html form**

```
  <form action="{% url 'index' %}" method="POST" target="_self">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="w3-row-padding" style="margin:0 -16px 8px -16px">
          <div class="w3-half">
            <input class="w3-input w3-border" type="text" placeholder="Name" required name="Name" >
          </div>
          <div class="w3-half">
            <input class="w3-input w3-border" type="email" placeholder="Email" required name="Email">
          </div>
        </div>
        <input class="w3-input w3-border" type="text" placeholder="Message" required name="Message" >
        <button class="w3-button w3-black w3-right w3-section" type="submit">
          <i class="fa fa-paper-plane"></i> SEND MESSAGE
        </button>
      </form>
```

Comment: need more detail. please put form and amin. isn't there any errors?

Comment: If you set DEBUG = True, does it throw any errors? What platform is the project deployed on?

Comment: Since i didn't use django form so i don't use forms.py. i am just using my html form @babakgholamirad

Comment: There is no error occured. The app works both in local and deployment @nightwolfgroup

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what platform you have deployed the project on, but one of the first things I would try is to make sure you have run database migration. (Which I'm assuming you have done if you have access to the admin area, but it might be worth running again just to make sure.)

```
python manage.py makemigrations
```

```
python manage.py migrate
```

I made some modifications to your HTML form to more closely follow the Django documentation. Notably, the addition of `enctype="multipart/form-data"` and an id tag to each input: i.e. `id="name"`. Here is a link to the documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/forms/

```html
<form action="{% url 'index' %}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="w3-row-padding" style="margin:0 -16px 8px -16px">
        <div class="w3-half">
            <input class="w3-input w3-border" type="text" placeholder="Name" name="Name" id="name" required>
        </div>
        <div class="w3-half">
            <input class="w3-input w3-border" type="email" placeholder="Email" name="Email" id="email" required>
        </div>
    </div>
    <input class="w3-input w3-border" type="text" placeholder="Message" name="Message" id="message" required>
    <button class="w3-button w3-black w3-right w3-section" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-paper-plane"></i>SEND MESSAGE</button>
</form>
```

It could be an issue with copying/pasting code, but I noticed the fields on your model are over-indented. Make sure you are using a single tab before each field.

```py
# models.py
class Feedback(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    email = models.EmailField()
    message = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

If you are able to see the terminal, are you getting a 200 response with your POST request? It should look something like this:

```
"POST / HTTP/1.1" 200
```

One of the other things I'd check is to ensure your database is configured properly in settings.py (This is assuming you are using the sqlite database)

```py
# settings.py
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}
```

If you aren't seeing anything in the admin area, make sure you have registered your model in admin.py

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Feedback

admin.site.register(Feedback)
```

Comment: Thank you for giving some feedback. But the problem is not yet solved. I still can't get the data from the form after the app is deployed. Also I have tried to change my database from **sqlite3** to **postgres**. And it still won't work